# Java Applet to ping an IP address

Tags: java

I made this code and it gives the following 3 errors! I need help to get away with these errors that are there in the attached image. The 3 errors that are arising aren't going away since i don't have much info about how to include system commands.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class EventListeners extends Applet 
implements ActionListener{
public void init(){
Button b = new Button("Ping");
b.addActionListener(this);
add(b);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
runSystemCommand(String command)
{try {
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String s = "";
// reading output stream of the command
while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(s);
}}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}}

public static void main(String[] args) {

String ip = "google.com";
runSystemCommand("ping " + ip); 





}  
}
![Errors][1]
```

Comment: You seem to be declaring a method withing method

Comment: well, the error is quite obvious .

Comment: I have to earn 10 reputations to post the errors image :o

Comment: How much reputation is required to correctly format the code? :-)

Comment: Any relation to two previous questions? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447047/java-applet-that-pings-an-ip-address) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453008/ping-ip-address)?

Comment: So you deleted your account and made a new one to ask the same question again with no improvements? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453008/ping-ip-address?rq=1   And as im suspecting again here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447047/java-applet-that-pings-an-ip-address?rq=1

Comment: @BhavnaSultana we were in those other two question. We tried to explain to you how to imnprove your question so that we are able to answer it. The fact that that didn't happen plus your strange behaviour with recreating your account lead to this...

Comment: @stonedsquirrel- yes i am the one. I have been trying to make this code and i have really tried but i get stuck up since i don't know about system commands, actually entire networking!

Comment: @stonedsquirrel- i am sorry, i just deleted my account cuz it was connected to my fb account and that was to be deactivated. In order to be able to ask the que again, i reactivated the other one. sorry if i acted like stange.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to write a function within a method.  This is illegal in Java

Place you `runSystemCommand` method out side the `actionPerformed` method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // Call runSystemCommand(...);
}

public void runSystemCommand(String command) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s = "";
        // reading output stream of the command
        while ((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Some caveats...

Applets run in a tight security sandbox.  It will NOT allow you to run system commands.  Even if it, you could possible be running on a Linux or Mac box instead of Windows.

If you want to start with GUI program, start with something like `JFrame`, much easier to work with

I would also suggest getting your hands on a suitable IDE

Comment: Mad but kind I see... I wouldn't have answered this question.. :-P +1

Comment: If the comments had being there before, neither would have I :P